# Save uploaded excel in database

Tags: java, excel, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a code where my client send an excel file to the server. The server (SpringBoot)
needs to 'translate' the `MultiplartFile` to an excel File.
From then, the data needs to be inserted into a database.

However, I never need to generate an excel but rather should insert the data from the spreadsheet into the database directly.

I first tried with :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
@ResponseBody
public MyMessage insertExcell(@RequestPart("typeFile") String typeFile,
        @RequestPart("uploadFile") MultipartFile multipart, @RequestPart("dataUser") DataUser dataUser) {

    BufferedReader br;
    List<String> result2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        String line;
        InputStream is = multipart.getInputStream();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result2.add(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < result2.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("sentence" + result2.get(i));;
    }
```

The output returns strange symbols.

Then again i tried with :

```
InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = multipart.getInputStream ();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println("linea era" + line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The console output shows strange symbols.

How can i read the data from the excel file uploaded ?

Comment: do you have any question? please describe your problem where you need help more specific.

Comment: I need read MultipartFile ... because I need do insert in database the data the Excell (MultipartFile ) , but when I read MultipartFile with getInputStream o with ByteArray I always get rare simbols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i understand, you need to read an Excel file, get your data then save it into a database.

Excel files are stored in various formats :

- Excel 2003 Binary file format (BIFF8).
- Xml Based format (for .xlsx)

If you simply try to read such a file, this would be quite a task...

Fortunately, [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/index.html) has a library that should help.

You can download it [here](https://poi.apache.org/download.html).

Here is a simple example on how to read your excel file :

```
try (InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream())
    {
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        // opening the first sheet
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0); 
        // read the third row
        Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
        // read 4th cell
        Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
        // get the string value
        String myValue = cell.getStringCellValue();

        // store in the database...         
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO
    }
```